# Adding an Option[T] to an Option[Seq[T]]

Tags: scala, option-type

Having an `Option[Seq[String]]`, I'm trying to find the best way to add an `Option[String]` to that collection, resulting again in an `Option[Seq[String]]`. If the collection is `None`, but the value to add is `Some[String]`, the result should be `Option[Seq[String]]` with that single value.

I've come up with two ways to write this, which essentially boil down to the same. I feel like there must be a better way to do this. Any suggestions?

```
val messages: Option[Seq[String]] = Some(Seq("item"))
val message: Option[String] = Some("item 2")

val opt1: Option[Seq[String]] = message match {
  case Some(message) => Some(messages.map(_ :+ message).getOrElse(Seq(message)))
  case None          => messages
}

val opt2: Option[Seq[String]] = message
  .map(msg => Some(messages.map(_ :+ msg).getOrElse(Seq(msg))))
  .getOrElse(messages)

println(opt1) // Some(List(item, item 2))
println(opt2) // Some(List(item, item 2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `messages` are available. Convert `message` to Seq and add it to existing message.

Else convert `message` to `Option[Seq[String]]`

```
messages.map(msgs => msgs ++ message.toSeq)
  .orElse(message.map(x => Seq(x)))
```

clear syntax

```
 messages.map(_ ++ message.toSeq) orElse message.map(Seq(_))
```

## Scala REPL

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  def addOption[T](messages: Option[Seq[T]], message: Option[T]): Option[Seq[T]] =
    messages.map(msgs => msgs ++ message.toSeq)
      .orElse(message.map(Seq(_)))


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

addOption: [T](messages: Option[Seq[T]], message: Option[T])Option[Seq[T]]

scala> addOption(Some(Seq(1)), Some(2))
res4: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2))

scala> addOption(Some(Seq(1)), Some(3))
res5: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(List(1, 3))

scala> addOption(Some(Seq(1)), None)
res6: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(List(1))

scala> addOption(None, None)
res7: Option[Seq[Nothing]] = None

scala> addOption(None, Some(1))
res8: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(List(1))

scala> addOption(None, Some(2))
res9: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(List(2))
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `messages.map(_ ++ message.toSeq) orElse message.map(Seq(_))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one:

```
def push[T](message: Option[T], messages: Option[Seq[T]]): Option[Seq[T]] =
  message.map(s => messages.getOrElse(Nil) :+ s).orElse(messages)
```

which produces:

```
push(Some("!"), Some(Seq("hello", "world"))) // Some(List(hello, world, !))
push(None, Some(List("hello", "world")))     // Some(List(hello, world))
push(Some("!"), None)                        // Some(List(!))
push(None, None)                             // None
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `fold` opt2 becomes:

```
val opt2: Option[Seq[String]] =
  message.fold(messages)(msg => Some(messages.fold(Seq(msg))(_ :+ msg)))
```

[ Automatic conversion by Intellij :) ]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using [fold](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#fold[B](ifEmpty:=%3EB)(f:A=%3EB):B):

```
def addOptMsg[T](msgs: Option[Seq[T]], msg: Option[T]): Option[Seq[T]] =
  msgs.fold( msg.map(Seq(_)) )( s => Option(s ++ msg.toSeq) )
```

Testing the method:

```
val messages: Option[Seq[String]] = Some(Seq("item1", "item2"))
val message: Option[String] = Some("item3")

val messages0: Option[Seq[String]] = None
val message0: Option[String] = None

addOptMsg(messages, message)
// res1: Option[Seq[String]] = Some(List(item1, item2, item3))

addOptMsg(messages, message0)
// res2: Option[Seq[String]] = Some(List(item1, item2))

addOptMsg(messages0, message)
// res3: Option[Seq[String]] = Some(List(item3))

addOptMsg(messages0, message0)
// res4: Option[Seq[String]] = None
```